# How to customize the form of a work item type using code in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to customize a work item programmatically (through code) instead of using the UI (Process)? I want to add a button to create two specific work items, provided some conditions are fulfilled.

I tried to achieve the above requirement using UI. However, it doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: When you want to add a button?

Comment: I want to do customization through code.

Answer (score 0):

For processes using the Inheritance model. API’s for everything you need to create and manage a process through code. This includes work item types, pages, groups, fields, states, rules, etc. Check `Work Item Tracking Process` APIs at the following site:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

For Hosted XML processes. API’s for checking to see if the process exists, importing, and exporting a Hosted XML process. Check `Work Item Tracking Process Template` APIs.

More details, you could refer to the following blog:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/announcing-new-rest-apis-for-process-customization/